# what is the probability of P(A' or B')?

Tags: probability, independence

P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.2 assuming independent events

what is the probability of not A or not B?

I thought I could substitute P(A') = 1-P(A) and P(B') = 1-P(B) so:

P(A' or B') = 1-P(A) + 1-P(B) = 0.3 + 0.8 = 1.1

but 1.1 is greater than 1 so that can't be the correct answer
can someone help me with what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you can add the probabilities?

Comment: can't you add the probabilities together if it's an or statement such that P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)?

Comment: Does your textbook say so? Read it again: There must be some condition that tells when you can simply add probabilities and when you cannot.

Comment: mutual exclusivity? so if they're exclusive I can add otherwise i'd have to write P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) because I would be double counting intersection so for this I'd write P(A' or B') = 1-P(A') + 1-P(B') - P(A' and B')?

Comment: yes that is correct but you wanted to write $P (A' \cup B') = P(A') + P(B') - P(A' \cap B')$

Answer (score 1):

You say that A and B are independent but you do not say wheter or not they are *mutually exclusive*!

In general, P(A or B)= P(A)+ P(B)- P(A and B).  If A and B are disjoint so that P(A and B)= 0 then P(A or B)= P(A)+ P(B).

Here, you say that P(A)= 0.7 and p(B)= 0.2.  Those add to 0, so it is quite possible (but not certain) that they are mutually exclusive.  But P(A')= 0.3 and P(B')= 0.8.  Those add, as you saw, to 1.1> 0 so even if A and B are mutually exclusive, A' and B' **cannot be**!

Comment: -1 This argument is flawed. If $A$ and $B$ are given to be independent events with probabilities in $(0,1)$, then they cannot possibly be mutually exclusive.  Note that _by definition of independence_, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ is greater than $0$ because $P(A), P(B)$ are given to be greater than $0$, and so $A\cap B$ cannot possibly be the empty set as you continually harp on as a distinct possibility that must be ruled out.  No probability measure assigns nonzero probability to the empty set!